# About pointing to /detecting one function by multiple names (synonymous..)

Tags: c#, function-pointers, intellisense

e.g. In finance, there's a formula for calcualting certain values. Following two methods have the same implementation (formula), arguments and return type. I only need to have one function.

```
public double FullPrice(/*params*/){
   //method implementation
}

public double DirtyPrice(/*same params*/){
   //same implementation
}
```

While some in the industry refers to the formula name as FullPrice, some others refer to it as Dirty Price - synonym per se. If the function library to be focused on a variety of audience indpendent of the jargon, how can we have C# intellisense to refer to FullPrice function when DirtyPrice is typed and vise versa?

Is it possible or am I asking for some impossible, rather not waste time kind of a question? Two different names pointing to one function. Is it somewhat related to delegates or totally something else?

Comment: `public double DirtyPrice(/*params*/) { return FullPrice(/*params*/); }`

Comment: I still have to implement both methods in my code, haven't I?

Comment: Implement? No. One delegates to the other, so you only have one implementation. Define both methods? Yes, but that's literally as trivial as you can get. There's no conceivable syntactic sugar that would be any shorter or clearer.

Comment: @CodyGray Preciely I was looking for some magical **syntactic sugar**. Bulls eye! In that case I could just provide the documentation and give only one method too. It's just certain other calculation formulas can be much lengthier and harder. But certain delegates could help in not having interface chunks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what documentation is for. You create the library, you get to decide how to name the method. Document that "full price" is the same thing others refer to as the "dirty price".

If you really must:

```
public double FullPrice(/*params*/)
{
    return DirtyPrice(/*params*/);
}
```

But this will add a useless method to your API, which can cause confusion and will increase maintenance.

Comment: +1 *But this will add a useless method to your API, which can cause confusion and will increase maintenance*

Comment: @SriramSakthivel can you specify how useless it could get? and what sort of confusions? Like user's calling for *L3* support on method definitions? or something else?

Comment: @bonCodigo Assume if I know both the terms, I know `FullPrice` and `DirtyPrice` are same but I see two **different** methods in api, I will be definitely confused why two methods? What they do? How they differ? etc etc. Better to have an API with standard names not based on names used by few people.